# Replace icons with images

Tags: css

I use `https://boxicons.com/` to display the 3 icones. I share you [here](https://html-css-js.com/?html=%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%3Ctitle%3EHTML%20CSS%20JS%3C/title%3E%0A%3Cmeta%20charset=%22utf-8%22%3E%0A%3Cmeta%20name=%22viewport%22%20content=%22wi$*$dth=device-wi$*$dth,%20initial-scale=1%22%3E%0A%3Ctitle%3ELogin%3C/title%3E%0A%3Clink%20rel=%22icon%22%20type=%22image/x-icon%22%20href=%22favicon.ico%22%3E%0A%3Clink%20href=%22https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css%22%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20/%3E%0A%3Clink%20href=%27https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@2.0.5/css/boxicons.min.css%27%20rel=%27stylesheet%27%3E%0A%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css%22%20/%3E%0A%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22style.css%22%3E%0A%3C/head%3E%0A%3Cbody%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class=%22l-form%22%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class=%22shape1%22%3E%3C/div%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class=%22shape2%22%3E%3C/div%3E%0A%0A%3Cdiv%20class=%22form%22%3E%0A%3Cimg%20src=%22https://zupimages.net/up/22/33/al0n.png%22%20alt=%22image%22%20class=%22form__img%22%20style=%22wi$*$dth:%2070%25%22%3E%0A%0A%3Cform%20%20class=%22form__content%22%3E%0A%3Ch1%20class=%22form__title%22%3ELogin%3C/h1%3E%0A%0A%3Cdiv%20class=%22form__div%20form__div-one%22%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class=%22form__icon%22%3E%0A%3Ci%20class=%27bx%20bx-user-circle%27%3E%3C/i%3E%0A%3C/div%3E%0A%0A%3Cdiv%20class=%22form__div-input%22%3E%0A%3Clabel%20for=%22user%22%20class=%22form__label%22%3E%3C/label%3E%0A%3Cinput%20type=%22text%22%20class=%22form__input%22%20name=%22user%22%20%5B(ngModel)%5D=%22loginForm.user%22%20placeholder=%27Username%27%3E%0A%3C/div%3E%0A%3C/div%3E%0A%0A%0A%3Cinput%20type=%22submit%22%20class=%22form__button%22%20value=%27Login%27%3E%0A%0A%3Cdiv%20class=%22form__login%22%3E%0A%0A%3Cspan%20class=%22form__login-text%22%3EOur%20partners%3C/span%3E%0A%0A%3Ca%20href=%22#%22%20class=%22form__login-icon%22%3E%3Ci%20class=%27bx%20bx-book-content%27%3E%3C/i%3E%3C/a%3E%0A%3Ca%20href=%22#%22%20class=%22form__login-icon%22%3E%3Ci%20class=%27bx%20bx-building-house%27%3E%3C/i%3E%3C/a%3E%0A%3Ca%20href=%22#%22%20class=%22form__login-icon%22%3E%3Ci%20class=%27bx%20bx-wallet-alt%27%3E%3C/i%3E%3C/a%3E%0A%0A%3C/div%3E%0A%3C/form%3E%0A%3C/div%3E%0A%0A%3C/div%3E%0A%3C/body%3E%0A%3C/html%3E%0A&css=body%20%7B%0A%20%20margin:%200;%0A%20%20padding:%200;%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20img%20%7B%0A%20%20max-wi$*$dth:%20100%25;%0A%20%20height:%20auto;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.l-form%20%7B%0A%20%20position:%20relative;%0A%20%20height:%20100vh;%0A%20%20overflow:%20hi$*$dden;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.shape1,%0A%20%20.shape2%20%7B%0A%20%20position:%20absolute;%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%20200px;%0A%20%20height:%20200px;%0A%20%20border-radius:%2050%25;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.shape1%20%7B%0A%20%20top:%20-7rem;%0A%20%20left:%20-3.5rem;%0A%20%20background:%20linear-gradient(180deg,%20#239CD3%200%25,%20rgba(196,%20196,%20196,%200)%20100%25);%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.shape2%20%7B%0A%20%20bottom:%20-6rem;%0A%20%20right:%20-5.5rem;%0A%20%20background:%20linear-gradient(180deg,%20#239CD3%200%25,%20rgba(196,%20196,%20196,%200)%20100%25);%0A%20%20transform:%20rotate(180deg);%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form%20%7B%0A%20%20height:%20100vh;%0A%20%20display:%20gri$*$d;%0A%20%20justify-content:%20center;%0A%20%20align-items:%20center;%0A%20%20padding:%200%201rem;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__content%20%7B%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%20290px;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__img%20%7B%0A%20%20display:%20none;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__title%20%7B%0A%20%20font-size:%202rem;%0A%20%20font-weight:%20500;%0A%20%20margin-bottom:%202rem;%0A%20%20color:%20#239CD3;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__div%20%7B%0A%20%20position:%20relative;%0A%20%20display:%20gri$*$d;%0A%20%20gri$*$d-template-columns:%207%25%2093%25;%0A%20%20margin-bottom:%201rem;%0A%20%20padding:%200.25rem%200;%0A%20%20border-bottom:%201px%20soli$*$d%20#8590AD;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.form__div.focus%20%7B%0A%20%20border-bottom:%201px%20soli$*$d%20#8590AD;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.form__div.focus%20.form__icon%20%7B%0A%20%20color:%20red;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.form__div.focus%20.form__label%20%7B%0A%20%20top:%20-1.5rem;%0A%20%20font-size:%200.875rem;%0A%20%20color:%20red;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__div-one%20%7B%0A%20%20margin-bottom:%203rem;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__icon%20%7B%0A%20%20font-size:%201.5rem;%0A%20%20color:%20#8590AD;%0A%20%20transition:%200.3s;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__label%20%7B%0A%20%20display:%20block;%0A%20%20position:%20absolute;%0A%20%20left:%200.75rem;%0A%20%20top:%200.25rem;%0A%20%20font-size:%200.938rem;%0A%20%20transition:%200.3s;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__div-input%20%7B%0A%20%20position:%20relative;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__input%20%7B%0A%20%20position:%20absolute;%0A%20%20top:%200;%0A%20%20left:%200;%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%20100%25;%0A%20%20height:%20100%25;%0A%20%20border:%20none;%0A%20%20outline:%20none;%0A%20%20background:%20none;%0A%20%20padding:%200.5rem%200.75rem;%0A%20%20font-size:%201.2rem;%0A%20%20color:%20#8590AD;%0A%20%20transition:%200.3s;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__button%20%7B%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%20100%25;%0A%20%20padding:%201rem;%0A%20%20font-size:%200.938rem;%0A%20%20outline:%20none;%0A%20%20border:%20none;%0A%20%20margin-bottom:%203rem;%0A%20%20background-color:%20#239CD3;%0A%20%20color:%20#fff;%0A%20%20border-radius:%200.5rem;%0A%20%20cursor:%20pointer;%0A%20%20transition:%200.3s;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.form__button:hover%20%7B%0A%20%20box-shadow:%200px%2015px%2036px%20rgba(0,%200,%200,%200.15);%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__login%20%7B%0A%20%20text-align:%20center;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__login-text%20%7B%0A%20%20display:%20block;%0A%20%20font-size:%200.938rem;%0A%20%20margin-bottom:%201rem;%0A%20%20color:%20#239CD3;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__login-icon%20%7B%0A%20%20display:%20inline-flex;%0A%20%20justify-content:%20center;%0A%20%20align-items:%20center;%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%2030px;%0A%20%20height:%2030px;%0A%20%20margin-right:%201rem;%0A%20%20padding:%200.5rem;%0A%20%20background-color:%20#8590AD;%0A%20%20color:%20#fff;%0A%20%20font-size:%201.25rem;%0A%20%20border-radius:%2050%25;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.form__login-icon:hover%20%7B%0A%20%20background-color:%20#239CD3;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%0A%20%20%0A%20%20/*=====%20MEDIA%20QUERIS%20=====*/%0A%20%20@media%20screen%20and%20(min-wi$*$dth:%20968px)%20%7B%0A%20%20.shape1%20%7B%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%20400px;%0A%20%20height:%20400px;%0A%20%20top:%20-11rem;%0A%20%20left:%20-6.5rem;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.shape2%20%7B%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%20300px;%0A%20%20height:%20300px;%0A%20%20right:%20-6.5rem;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.form%20%7B%0A%20%20gri$*$d-template-columns:%201.5fr%201fr;%0A%20%20padding:%200%202rem;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.form__content%20%7B%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%20320px;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.form__img%20%7B%0A%20%20display:%20block;%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%20700px;%0A%20%20justify-self:%20center;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D&js=//%20JavaScript%0Adocument.getElementById(%27welcome%27).innerText%20+=%20%0A%22%20Editors%22;%0A) the code.

[image]

Except that, I would like to download the icons to keep them in a folder.

Here is the result with uploaded images:

[image]

The code is [here](https://html-css-js.com/?html=%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Chead%3E%0A%3Ctitle%3EHTML%20CSS%20JS%3C/title%3E%0A%3Cmeta%20charset=%22utf-8%22%3E%0A%3Cmeta%20name=%22viewport%22%20content=%22wi$*$dth=device-wi$*$dth,%20initial-scale=1%22%3E%0A%3Ctitle%3ELogin%3C/title%3E%0A%3Clink%20rel=%22icon%22%20type=%22image/x-icon%22%20href=%22favicon.ico%22%3E%0A%3Clink%20href=%22https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css%22%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20/%3E%0A%3Clink%20href=%27https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@2.0.5/css/boxicons.min.css%27%20rel=%27stylesheet%27%3E%0A%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css%22%20/%3E%0A%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22style.css%22%3E%0A%3C/head%3E%0A%3Cbody%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class=%22l-form%22%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class=%22shape1%22%3E%3C/div%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class=%22shape2%22%3E%3C/div%3E%0A%0A%3Cdiv%20class=%22form%22%3E%0A%3Cimg%20src=%22https://zupimages.net/up/22/33/al0n.png%22%20alt=%22image%22%20class=%22form__img%22%20style=%22wi$*$dth:%2070%25%22%3E%0A%0A%3Cform%20%20class=%22form__content%22%3E%0A%3Ch1%20class=%22form__title%22%3ELogin%3C/h1%3E%0A%0A%3Cdiv%20class=%22form__div%20form__div-one%22%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class=%22form__icon%22%3E%0A%3Ci%20class=%27bx%20bx-user-circle%27%3E%3C/i%3E%0A%3C/div%3E%0A%0A%3Cdiv%20class=%22form__div-input%22%3E%0A%3Clabel%20for=%22user%22%20class=%22form__label%22%3E%3C/label%3E%0A%3Cinput%20type=%22text%22%20class=%22form__input%22%20name=%22user%22%20%5B(ngModel)%5D=%22loginForm.user%22%20placeholder=%27Username%27%3E%0A%3C/div%3E%0A%3C/div%3E%0A%0A%0A%3Cinput%20type=%22submit%22%20class=%22form__button%22%20value=%27Login%27%3E%0A%0A%3Cdiv%20class=%22form__login%22%3E%0A%0A%3Cspan%20class=%22form__login-text%22%3EOur%20partners%3C/span%3E%0A%0A%3Ca%20href=%22#%22%20class=%22form__login-icon%22%3E%3Cimg%20src=%22https://zupimages.net/up/22/33/qad0.png%22%20alt=%22image%22%3E%3C/a%3E%0A%3Ca%20href=%22#%22%20class=%22form__login-icon%22%3E%3Cimg%20src=%22https://zupimages.net/up/22/33/8mhc.png%22%20alt=%22image%22%3E%3C/a%3E%0A%3Ca%20href=%22#%22%20class=%22form__login-icon%22%3E%3Cimg%20src=%22https://zupimages.net/up/22/33/qq74.png%22%20alt=%22image%22%3E%3C/a%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%0A%3C/div%3E%0A%3C/form%3E%0A%3C/div%3E%0A%0A%3C/div%3E%0A%3C/body%3E%0A%3C/html%3E%0A&css=body%20%7B%0A%20%20margin:%200;%0A%20%20padding:%200;%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20img%20%7B%0A%20%20max-wi$*$dth:%20100%25;%0A%20%20height:%20auto;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.l-form%20%7B%0A%20%20position:%20relative;%0A%20%20height:%20100vh;%0A%20%20overflow:%20hi$*$dden;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.shape1,%0A%20%20.shape2%20%7B%0A%20%20position:%20absolute;%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%20200px;%0A%20%20height:%20200px;%0A%20%20border-radius:%2050%25;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.shape1%20%7B%0A%20%20top:%20-7rem;%0A%20%20left:%20-3.5rem;%0A%20%20background:%20linear-gradient(180deg,%20#239CD3%200%25,%20rgba(196,%20196,%20196,%200)%20100%25);%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.shape2%20%7B%0A%20%20bottom:%20-6rem;%0A%20%20right:%20-5.5rem;%0A%20%20background:%20linear-gradient(180deg,%20#239CD3%200%25,%20rgba(196,%20196,%20196,%200)%20100%25);%0A%20%20transform:%20rotate(180deg);%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form%20%7B%0A%20%20height:%20100vh;%0A%20%20display:%20gri$*$d;%0A%20%20justify-content:%20center;%0A%20%20align-items:%20center;%0A%20%20padding:%200%201rem;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__content%20%7B%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%20290px;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__img%20%7B%0A%20%20display:%20none;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__title%20%7B%0A%20%20font-size:%202rem;%0A%20%20font-weight:%20500;%0A%20%20margin-bottom:%202rem;%0A%20%20color:%20#239CD3;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__div%20%7B%0A%20%20position:%20relative;%0A%20%20display:%20gri$*$d;%0A%20%20gri$*$d-template-columns:%207%25%2093%25;%0A%20%20margin-bottom:%201rem;%0A%20%20padding:%200.25rem%200;%0A%20%20border-bottom:%201px%20soli$*$d%20#8590AD;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.form__div.focus%20%7B%0A%20%20border-bottom:%201px%20soli$*$d%20#8590AD;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.form__div.focus%20.form__icon%20%7B%0A%20%20color:%20red;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.form__div.focus%20.form__label%20%7B%0A%20%20top:%20-1.5rem;%0A%20%20font-size:%200.875rem;%0A%20%20color:%20red;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__div-one%20%7B%0A%20%20margin-bottom:%203rem;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__icon%20%7B%0A%20%20font-size:%201.5rem;%0A%20%20color:%20#8590AD;%0A%20%20transition:%200.3s;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__label%20%7B%0A%20%20display:%20block;%0A%20%20position:%20absolute;%0A%20%20left:%200.75rem;%0A%20%20top:%200.25rem;%0A%20%20font-size:%200.938rem;%0A%20%20transition:%200.3s;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__div-input%20%7B%0A%20%20position:%20relative;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__input%20%7B%0A%20%20position:%20absolute;%0A%20%20top:%200;%0A%20%20left:%200;%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%20100%25;%0A%20%20height:%20100%25;%0A%20%20border:%20none;%0A%20%20outline:%20none;%0A%20%20background:%20none;%0A%20%20padding:%200.5rem%200.75rem;%0A%20%20font-size:%201.2rem;%0A%20%20color:%20#8590AD;%0A%20%20transition:%200.3s;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__button%20%7B%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%20100%25;%0A%20%20padding:%201rem;%0A%20%20font-size:%200.938rem;%0A%20%20outline:%20none;%0A%20%20border:%20none;%0A%20%20margin-bottom:%203rem;%0A%20%20background-color:%20#239CD3;%0A%20%20color:%20#fff;%0A%20%20border-radius:%200.5rem;%0A%20%20cursor:%20pointer;%0A%20%20transition:%200.3s;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.form__button:hover%20%7B%0A%20%20box-shadow:%200px%2015px%2036px%20rgba(0,%200,%200,%200.15);%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__login%20%7B%0A%20%20text-align:%20center;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__login-text%20%7B%0A%20%20display:%20block;%0A%20%20font-size:%200.938rem;%0A%20%20margin-bottom:%201rem;%0A%20%20color:%20#239CD3;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20.form__login-icon%20%7B%0A%20%20display:%20inline-flex;%0A%20%20justify-content:%20center;%0A%20%20align-items:%20center;%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%2030px;%0A%20%20height:%2030px;%0A%20%20margin-right:%201rem;%0A%20%20padding:%200.5rem;%0A%20%20background-color:%20#8590AD;%0A%20%20color:%20#fff;%0A%20%20font-size:%201.25rem;%0A%20%20border-radius:%2050%25;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.form__login-icon:hover%20%7B%0A%20%20background-color:%20#239CD3;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%0A%20%20%0A%20%20/*=====%20MEDIA%20QUERIS%20=====*/%0A%20%20@media%20screen%20and%20(min-wi$*$dth:%20968px)%20%7B%0A%20%20.shape1%20%7B%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%20400px;%0A%20%20height:%20400px;%0A%20%20top:%20-11rem;%0A%20%20left:%20-6.5rem;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.shape2%20%7B%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%20300px;%0A%20%20height:%20300px;%0A%20%20right:%20-6.5rem;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.form%20%7B%0A%20%20gri$*$d-template-columns:%201.5fr%201fr;%0A%20%20padding:%200%202rem;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.form__content%20%7B%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%20320px;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20.form__img%20%7B%0A%20%20display:%20block;%0A%20%20wi$*$dth:%20700px;%0A%20%20justify-self:%20center;%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D&js=//%20JavaScript%0Adocument.getElementById(%27welcome%27).innerText%20+=%20%0A%22%20Editors%22;%0A)

I have two problems:

1. The white color is gone and it is replaced with black.
2. There is a horizontal line below the image that has disappeared

Do you know how I could get the same result as in the first illustration?

I just changed this

```
<span class="form__login-text">Our partners</span>

<a href="#" class="form__login-icon"><i class='bx bx-book-content'></i></a>
<a href="#" class="form__login-icon"><i class='bx bx-building-house'></i></a>
<a href="#" class="form__login-icon"><i class='bx bx-wallet-alt'></i></a>
```

In this

```
<span class="form__login-text">Our partners</span>

<a href="#" class="form__login-icon"><img src="https://zupimages.net/up/22/33/qad0.png" alt="image"></a>
<a href="#" class="form__login-icon"><img src="https://zupimages.net/up/22/33/8mhc.png" alt="image"></a>
<a href="#" class="form__login-icon"><img src="https://zupimages.net/up/22/33/qq74.png" alt="image"></a>
```

Thanks

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  }
  
  img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  }
  
  .l-form {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .shape1,
  .shape2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  }
  
  .shape1 {
  top: -7rem;
  left: -3.5rem;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #239CD3 0%, rgba(196, 196, 196, 0) 100%);
  }
  
  .shape2 {
  bottom: -6rem;
  right: -5.5rem;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #239CD3 0%, rgba(196, 196, 196, 0) 100%);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  
  .form {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  }
  
  .form__content {
  width: 290px;
  }
  
  .form__img {
  display: none;
  }
  
  .form__title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  color: #239CD3;
  }
  
  .form__div {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 7% 93%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8590AD;
  }
  .form__div.focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8590AD;
  }
  .form__div.focus .form__icon {
  color: red;
  }
  .form__div.focus .form__label {
  top: -1.5rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: red;
  }
  
  .form__div-one {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  }
  
  .form__icon {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #8590AD;
  transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  .form__label {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.75rem;
  top: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 0.938rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  .form__div-input {
  position: relative;
  }
  
  .form__input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #8590AD;
  transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  .form__button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 0.938rem;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  background-color: #239CD3;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  }
  .form__button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 36px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  }
  
  .form__login {
  text-align: center;
  }
  
  .form__login-text {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.938rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: #239CD3;
  }
  
  .form__login-icon {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #8590AD;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  }
  .form__login-icon:hover {
  background-color: #239CD3;
  }


  /*===== MEDIA QUERIS =====*/
  @media screen and (min-width: 968px) {
  .shape1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  top: -11rem;
  left: -6.5rem;
  }
  .shape2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  right: -6.5rem;
  }
  .form {
  grid-template-columns: 1.5fr 1fr;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  }
  .form__content {
  width: 320px;
  }
  .form__img {
  display: block;
  width: 700px;
  justify-self: center;
  }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@2.0.5/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="l-form">
<div class="shape1"></div>
<div class="shape2"></div>

<div class="form">
<img src="https://zupimages.net/up/22/33/al0n.png" alt="image" class="form__img" style="width: 70%">


<form  class="form__content">
<h1 class="form__title">Login</h1>

<div class="form__div form__div-one">
<div class="form__icon">
<i class='bx bx-user-circle'></i>
</div>

<div class="form__div-input">
<label for="user" class="form__label"></label>
<input type="text" class="form__input" name="user" [(ngModel)]="loginForm.user" placeholder='Username'>
</div>
</div>


<input type="submit" class="form__button" value='Login'>

<div class="form__login">

<span class="form__login-text">Our partners</span>

<!-- 
<a href="#" class="form__login-icon"><i class='bx bx-book-content'></i></a>
<a href="#" class="form__login-icon"><i class='bx bx-building-house'></i></a>
<a href="#" class="form__login-icon"><i class='bx bx-wallet-alt'></i></a>
-->

<a href="#" class="form__login-icon"><img src="https://zupimages.net/up/22/33/qad0.png" alt="image"></a>
<a href="#" class="form__login-icon"><img src="https://zupimages.net/up/22/33/8mhc.png" alt="image"></a>
<a href="#" class="form__login-icon"><img src="https://zupimages.net/up/22/33/qq74.png" alt="image"></a>
  

</div>
</form>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Icons act like text, so you can style it same way (size, color, etc...), but images cannot be styled with css, so to solve that problem you can edit the image with an external program like gimp or photoshop

Comment: You can't change the image color, if you want to deal up with different colors you have to use svg instead, or download the same image with two colors and change the source to your specific color when the user hover over it or something like that.... about the underline you have to add it alone using ::before or ::after in css

Comment: @Omar Zaoujal, So if I use an SVG it can work?

Comment: @juliette yes, for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the image you are using has black foreground. You can use `.form__login-icon img { filter: invert(1); }` to make the foreground white. For the horizontal line use `box-shadow: 0 2px #000;`. Otherwise use an SVG image and apply the fill color of your choice.

Comment: Thank you very much it works with your css, but how can I add the horizontal line, please?

Comment: Use `box-shadow` as I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the images. those images have black background though they are in PNG format.
You can use online tools, Adobe illustrator or photoshop to remove the background from those images. Or you can use images in SVG format